# Rails, how to use will_paginate with helper's variable and not with controller's variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, will-paginate

I'am trying to use the will_paginate gem for the paginating my entries on my view.
But I wanted to use the variable of helper instead of controller.
Have looked various tutorials and links but not got the solution.

Please help
thanks in advance!
Lakhan

Comment: can you paste your code here and be specific?

Comment: Please be more elaborate. At least add what you have tried so far